# Toggle checked state for an array of radio buttons React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, ionic-framework, toggle, jsx

How would I toggle the `checked` prop for a mapped array of items?

```
{Object.values(equipment).map((item, i) => {
    return (              
        <IonItem key={item}>
            <IonLabel>{item}</IonLabel>
            <IonRadio mode="md" slot="start" value={item} checked={false} onClick={} />
        </IonItem>
      );
    })
}
```

Comment: Are you using a Class based for function based component?

Comment: @dsadnick Im using functional components with Ionic Framework.

Comment: @dsadnick here I am mapping the object values inline with my React JSX.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this code but this would be a general approach to it.

Using reacts useState in a functional component could work for you.

```
// Import useState
import { useState } from 'react';

// Set your active and SetActive items
const [active, setActive] = useState({});

{Object.values(equipment).map((item, i) => {
    return (
        <IonItem key={item}>
            <IonLabel>{item}</IonLabel>
            <IonRadio mode="md" slot="start" value={item} checked={active.i || false} onClick={() => {
                // Set the specific Item to active
                setActive({i:!active.i});
            }} />
        </IonItem>
    );
})}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not think of approaching it this way! I tried implementing this but Im getting an error caused by the ```setActive({i:false});``` causing to many re renders?

Comment: @JordanSpackman I altered it a bit. But you still may need to alter it a bit to get it to work.